# Can you set Visual Studio 2017 CPU target for old CPU?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

Is there a way to setup Visual Studio 2017 to support older CPU?  Say one that doesn't have SSE2?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking to set up a project so that the *generated code* will run correctly on 'old' CPUs, or something more subtle? If the former, can you let us know what language(s) you are building your projects in (C, C++, basic, C#, etc.)?

Comment: Generated code to run on old Pentium CPU.   C/C++ project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select what CPU extensions to use (or not to use any) in the project's settings. The following works in VS2019 but, IIRC, it's *very* similar for VS2017.

In the solution explorer, right-click on the project and select "Properties" from the pop-up menu. Open the `C/C++` tree list and select the `Code Generation` page. Then, in the "Enable Enhanced Instruction Set" select the "No Enhanced Instructions" option (or "Not Set," if that isn't available), as below:

[image]

The "No Enhanced Instructions" option will instruct the compiler to use only the 'basic' Intel-x86 instruction set (which *should* work for a Pentium CPU).

The equivalent command-line option is `/arch:IA32`, which, as per [M/S Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/arch-x86?view=vs-2019):

> Specifies no enhanced instructions and also specifies x87 for
>   floating-point calculations.

*In older versions of MSVC, there was an option to include code guards against the "[Pentium FDIV Bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_FDIV_bug),"  (`/QIfdiv`) but it appears that has now been removed.*

Comment: Thanks!! I looked on that page but didn't see it.  Anyway, even though it says "Not Set", looking at the Dr Watson Dump (was on NT4), the instruction was in fact a SSE2 instruction .  FAULT ->0048e8ee 660fd6 - 66 0f d6 is  MOVQ

Comment: Have you tried explicitly adding /arch:IA32 in the "Additional Options" (in the "C/C++ -> Command Line" property page)?

Comment: No, it was sorta a one off, customer old specialized equipment using NT4, being in middle of upgrade haven't hand time to play around with it.  But it does make me curious if MSVC clib isn't built with SSE2 ?

Comment: @df2: The option *"Not Set"* means, that you aren't overriding the default from your .vcxproj file. You are using whatever is set as the default in your toolchain. You can quickly identify options that are set in your .vcxproj file: Those are displayed in **bold**. Everything else is not set in your .vcxproj, and uses the default.